# What is the complete list of ships in the Futurama Mobius Dick graveyard for us die hard scifi fans?

Tags: futurama, object-identification

In the episode [Möbius Dick](http://theinfosphere.org/M%C3%B6bius_Dick), the Planet Express crew travel trough a spaceship graveyard in Bermuda Tetrahedron. You could watch a video of this scene on [comedycentral.com](http://www.comedycentral.com/video-clips/do0dsg/futurama-the-wreck-of-the-original-planet-express-ship).

We have confirmed 13 of the ships and the rest look enticingly familiar but there are 60 years of shows to know and it's frustrating.  Help out a scifi fan of many years but worsening memory, please!

- Jupiter II
- Lunar lander module
- An Apollo Command/Service Module "Apollo 100"
- Saturn 5 launch stage
- Discovery One
- Monolith of Space Odyssey
- Satelite of Love from Mystery Science 3000
- Josey and the Pussycats in Space ship
- Boston's Guitar ship (best seen on Don't Look Back)
- Journey's Scarab Beetle ship
- ELO's Simon Says spaceship
- Skylab
- Oceanic Flight 815 from Lost
- Omicronian attack ship
- Starflight Arthling ship???
- Star Control Syreen penatrator???
- Ilrath Avenger???
- Umgah Drone???
- P'kunk Fury???
- Ariloulaleelay Skiff???
- V'ger???
- Ringed Space Station from... Silent Runnings???

Comment: I wasn't the downvote but is a screenshot possible?

Comment: @Dason There would have to be quite a few screenshots.  The scene is a minute or two long.

Comment: @Keen Fair enough - I haven't actually watched that episode for quite some time.

Comment: Maybe a YouTube link?

Comment: This has some of the items - http://theinfosphere.org/M%C3%B6bius_Dick

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but here's all the screenshots I could grab from the linked video. It should cover all this ships in that 2 min clip. http://imgur.com/a/7MtW2

Comment: Thankyou to @MajorStackings for getting my account issue notified to an admin.

I gave my guesses in the list followed by a '???' but they didn't answer this question in the Q&A so guess it may not get resolved.  The space station and the ship with the red engine nozzles from the screenshots linked above look so familiar.

Comment: I found some video's of various TV/movie and comic book ships.  Someone needs to make a top 100 ships of sci-fi gaming for Eve Online, Mass Effect, Wing Commander and others over the years.
100 with captions: http://youtu.be/88lmVxvRaXU
That 100 plus another 165: http://youtu.be/SrybSYaWpDE
Some others not above including Silent Runnings arboreal ships: http://youtu.be/GCpIuuK6uu4
Old fashioned list: http://youtu.be/7UZVN_ySgRQ
This one has many of this list: http://youtu.be/m2Chxm88xrg
Some more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNLskO8ZJsI&feature=share&list=PLBEA9728CFD5E5CBE

Answer (score 7):

As commented by OrionDarkwood, [The Info Sphere](http://theinfosphere.org/M%C3%B6bius_Dick#Space_ship_graveyard) lists some of them. Those in italics you already have, those in bold you don't.

- *Discovery One from 2001: A Space Odyssey*
- *A black monolith from 2001: A Space Odyssey*
- *Oceanic Flight 815 from Lost*
- *The spaceship used on album covers for the rock group Electric Light Orchestra*
- *An Omicronian mothership or the Hubble Telescope as seen in "When Aliens Attack"*
- *The Satellite of Love from Mystery Science Theater 3000*
- *The spaceship from Josie and the Pussycats in Outer Space*
- *The Jupiter 2 from Lost in Space*
- **Stereotypical UFO**
- **Garmin GPS satellite**[image: Lockheed Martin drawing of a Garmin Sat]
- **TomTom GPS satellite**[image: Nederlands based TomTom satnav]
- **First Planet Express ship**
- *An Apollo Command/Service Module labelled "Apollo 100"*
- *An Apollo Lunar Module*
- *The scarab beetle spaceship used on album covers for the band Journey*
- *The Skylab space station*
- *The guitar spaceship used on album covers for the band Boston*

The Garmin and TomTom aren't pointed out but are mentioned by Hermes in the video, and I think the suggestion is they were spaceships that got lost rather than satellites.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_Dick_%28Futurama%29#Cultural_references) adds nothing new, other to point out the Apollo Lunar Module has ascent and descent stages still attached, and the [Futurama Wiki](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_Dick) lists none.

I don't think there were any ringed space station in *Silent Runnings*.

I'm not sure if this is correct, but a post on the [Straight Dope Message Board](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=619379):

> I couldn't tell from the resolution of the picture onscreen, but I'm pretty sure there was also an old Type 40 Galifreyan TARDIS in the shape of a Police box there as well...

Finally, there's a green ship (in the centre of the first screenshot and right side of the second) that looks a bit like [Thunderbird 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_machines#Thunderbird_2)[image: Thunderbird 2].

Comment: That longer ship looks more like the Event Horizon to me than the Satellite of Love. The Satellite of Love has double bulb-like shapes and looks more like a cartoon dogbone

Answer (score 0):

The yellow and red one on the bottom left corner looks like the ship from "Earth Girls are Easy."